# Find the distance of a segment and explain your answer

Tags: geometry

[image: Find the distance]

The question asked to find the distance from J to GH. Would J be considered the incenter? Why? Can someone please explain this question to me?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, GJ bisects angle IGH but then IJ does NOT bisect angle KIH so, no, J is NOT the incenter.

Comment: ok. What would you call J in relation to the triangle then? Does it have a special name?

Comment: @user247327 Also how do you know for sure GJ bisects IJ

Comment: @coffeemath I think the 64.3 refers to the side length,no?

Comment: @Lil Yes (deleting comment) But on my copy the marking of the other angle is quite faint, looks like 23 but not sure.

Comment: Lil, the other number 82.1: is that the distance IJ or an angle?

Comment: @coffeemath I'd say distance because there isn't a degree symbol.

Comment: Is the faint 23 at angle G a 23 degree angle, like the other clearly marked one at G?

Comment: @coffeemath the faint 23 was just me playing around. Ignore the faint numbers please

Comment: The problem cannot be solved without further data.